# Java Multithreading with Asyncronous method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using ThreadPool concept to create 100 Threads. But i am passing List of 1000 emails as cleaned Emails.
After sometime Exception comes

> ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool

How can i resolve that error:

Here is my code:

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

    for (String email:cleanedEmails) {  
        Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(email);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    // Wait until all threads are finish
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

    }
    System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");

}

public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String email;

    MyRunnable(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void run() {

        DomainDetails obj=null;
        try 
        {
            HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("XXXXX")
                .header("X-Mashape-Key", "XXXXXX")
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .asJson();

            String response1=response.getBody().toString();

             obj=new ObjectMapper().readValue(response1, DomainDetails.class);
             System.out.println(email+ "\t\tExist:" +obj.getExist() );

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Increase the timeout, or use fewer threads.

Comment: I am not setting anywhere timeout. Also I have to validate more data so i need more threads.

Comment: doing while (!executor.isTerminated()); is a VERY bad idea. Replace it with something like
if (!executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)) {
//Something clearly went wrong
}

Comment: If i am using only 10 threads then it is working fine. But i need to complete my tasl faster so i need to use more threads. If i am using more threads then  Exception came:org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool